# What is role of #!usr/bin/perl -n?

Tags: perl

What is the role of `#!usr/bin/perl -n`? I am tried to refer to the books and other sources but i am not get the better idea. It behave like the STDIN, for example `my @array = <>` many input is store into the `@array`. `-n` also behave like this but how to store the input value in data types.? And which is the original function?

Comment: [-n in the perlrun docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-n*)

Comment: Take a look at the command switches section of [`perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Comment: Before perlrun I would do `perl -h`. That's usually sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

It essentially provides you the plumbing of wrapping what you put on the command line inside:

```
while (<>) {  ... What you have on cmd line here ... }
```

So:

```
perl -e 'while (<>) { if (/^(\w+):/) { print "$1\n"; } }'
```

and this:

```
perl -n -e 'if (/^(\w+):/) { print "$1\n" }'
```

are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

with the -n option, the code in the script will be interpreted as if you writed this :

```
while (<>) {
   <code>
}
```

for example, the following script, called with a file as an argument will replace all the end of line of the file and send the result on the standard output:

```
#!usr/bin/perl -n
~s/\n//;
print ;
```

it must be called like this:

```
perl script.pl <file>
```